# Find all integral solutions of $ x^4 + y^4 + z^4 -w^4 = 1995 $

Tags: number-theory

Find all integral solutions of $ x^4 + y^4 + z^4 -w^4 = 1995 $.

Attempt:
From FLT it can be concluded that either all of $ x , y , z$ and $w$  are multiples of 5 ( which is not possible since that would lead to $ x^4 + y^4 + z^4 -w^4 $ being a multiple of $5^4$ which it is not since it's equal to 1995) or
$ w^4 $ and  exactly one of $x^4, y^4, z^4 $ are of the form $5k+1$ .
So, there can be 3 cases with each having either $x^4, y^4  $ or $ z^4 $, along with $w^4$ , of the form $5k+1$ .
I am unable to find the solutions from there.

Comment: Math today problem?

Comment: This comes under on going contest. I request the mods to close this

Comment: I got this problem from a book called "Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics" . It's correspondence with any ongoing contest is coincidental.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that fourth powers are always congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod $16$. This can be proved using case analysis. I'll list these cases:

- If $n$ is even, then $2 \mid n$ hence $16 \mid n^4$.
- If $n\equiv \pm1 \mod 16$, then $n^4 \equiv 1 \mod 16$
- If $n\equiv \pm3 \mod 16$, then $n^4 \equiv 3^4 \equiv 1 \mod 16$
- If $n\equiv \pm5 \mod 16$, then $n^4 \equiv 5^4 \equiv 1 \mod 16$
- If $n\equiv \pm7 \mod 16$, then $n^4 \equiv 7^4 \equiv 1 \mod 16$

Now, the left hand side can be $-1, 0, 1, 2$ or $3$ mod $16$, but $1995$ is congruent to $11$ mod $16$.

Comment: So, there are no integral solutions?

Comment: @D.K Yes, it means that there are no solutions in integers.

Comment: Alternatively, you can prove that $n^4-1$ is divisible by $16$ for any odd $n$ via the factorization $$n^4-1=\left(n^2-1\right)\left(n^2+1\right)\,.$$

Answer (score 5):

Just an addendum to wythagoras fine (+1) answer. $x^4\in\{0,1\}\pmod{16}$ can be proved by observing that if $x$ is even, $x^4$ is clearly a multiple of $16$, while
$$ (2k+1)^4-1 = 2k(2k+2)(4k^2+4k+2) = 16\binom{k+1}{2}(2k^2+2k+1) $$
gives $(2k+1)^4\equiv 1\pmod{16}$.